# Regarding billabillity

Tags: software-industry

I am in a project from past two months still unbillable .
will I get my variable pay?
When asked to manager he says it wont be any problem.
But I have doubt
please do clarify

Comment: How would we know? That's a question for your boss, who has already answered it.

Comment: Why do you have doubt, if your manager says so?

Answer (score 4):

Relax, don't panic.

I am guessing that this is your first job where you would be billable. Probably your first job.

Your company knows that not everyone will working on something billable, all of the time, and they set their prices accordingly.

Trust your manager when he says that it will not affect your pay. You have a contract, don't you? Read it again. It it says anything about variable pay, then you need to update your question. If it does not, please don't panic.

What you *should* do though, is ask your manager how to fill your time, if you are not being given enough work to do. Maybe you learn about existing projects? That will show you how the company develops software. It will also allow you to support someone else, if they get ill, or take over the project, if the current owner gets moved.

Maybe your manager wants you to learn new skills?

If they have given you something to do, then you have no reason to worry. It is management's probable to find you billable work, and that is outside of your control. They know this.

If you are ***still*** worried, talk to some of your colleagues, and ask about the times that they had no billable work.

I am sure that it will all be just fine.